# Fancybox add stylesheet to parent page

Tags: jquery, fancybox, parent

I have this code to add a stylesheet to a page in a fancybox iframe. Can I do the same to the parent page?

I have tried this but it didn't work...

`window.parent.changeStyles(stylesheet)`;

function changeStyles(styles) {
$("", { 
                       rel: "stylesheet", 
                       type: "text/css", 
                       href: styles
                    }).appendTo("head"); 
                };

```
            $('.change-styles').on('click',function(){                              
                var stylesheet = $(this).attr('href');
                changeStyles(stylesheet);


                return false
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a parent file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the iframe file as `iframe.html`:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

function addCSSToParent(url) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = url;
    link.type = 'text/css';
    window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}

// Add some CSS
addCSSToParent('some.css');

</script>
</head>

<body>This is the iframe.</body>
</html>
```

The `addCSSToParent()` will add a new DOM element into the head of its parent with the given URL. Make sure to run this in a server environment, because accessing the parent worked but gave a few security errors in Chrome.

Comment: This doesn't target the parent page though which is what I need. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the JS is running inside an iframe and you'd like it to add CSS to the parent?

Comment: Sorry. Yes. Didn't explain that too well

Comment: This works well in most browser except IE8. I had to add the createStyleSheet(stylesheet) function for IE. Thanks